Error Call to undefined function set_value()
CodeIgniter4 Error Call to undefined function set_value() search → login.php at line 33 <div class="input-group custom"> 30             <input 31                 type="text" 32                 class="form-control form-control-lg" 33                 placeholder="Username or Email" name="login_id" value="<?= set_value('login_id') ?>" > 34             <div class="input-group-append custom"> 35                 <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-copy dw dw-user1"></i></span> 36             </div> 37         </div> 38         <?php if($validation->getError(('login_id'))):?> 39             <div class="d block text danger" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-bottom: 15px;"> 40                 <?= $validation->getError('login_id')?>   try { 366             return $this->handleRequest($routes, $cacheConfig, $returnResponse); 367         } catch (RedirectException $e) { 368             $logger = Services::logger(); 369             $logger->info('REDIRECTED ROUTE at ' . $e->geyour texttMessage()); 370 371             // If the route is a 'redirect' route, it throws 372             // the exception with the $to as the message 373             $this->response->redirect(base_url($e->getMessage()), 'auto', $e->getCode()); your text`` I search online and I got set_value('login_id') your text
i am looking for answer

Please [edit] your question into a more readable format. [ask] might be a good place to start

Did you load the form_helper as described here? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#loading-this-helper

Try this at line 33.
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Username or Email" name="login_id" value="<?= set_value('login_id', $this->session->userdata('current_client')); ?>" >

This would use the session var as the default value for the form field.
Read fo more details here: set_value() default in CodeIgniter
